# VSCode Python - print statement not printing to output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode. I have set it up on Windows. When I run it using Code Runner,I see Running and Done messages but the print statements are not working.

```
print("Hello World!")
print ("This is VS Code")
a=1
while a <10:
    print a
    a = a+ 1
```

Here is the output:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\user\PythonWorkArea\VSCode\HelloWorld\app.py"
[![\[Done\] exited with code=0 in 0.293 seconds][1]][1]
```

The print statement is not working.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so `print X` or `print(X)`? Made up your mind. And initialize `a`

Comment: Strange because `a` is not defined. I would expect an error.

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Comment: I tried with just print("Hello World!") and even that is not printing.There is something wrong with the configuration.

Comment: @Shankze Your VSCode is showing one unsaved file. Did you save before running?

Comment: You are on the Output tab which includes various logs from VS Code and not necessarily the programs you are running. You should use the Terminal tab.

Answer (score 1):

You should select the appropriate Python Environment that you are using, do Control+Shift+P -> Python: Select Interpreter.

I had the same issue and had to change the default env to get it working.

Comment: I did this and it wasn't helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("Hello world!")
print("This is VS Code")
a = 0
while a < 10:
    print(a)
    a += 1
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with the configuration, not with the code. It is not even throwing an error message.

Comment: @Shanke, hmmm... Did you try to run this from default windows command-line, not from VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

"a" has not been defined. Im surprised you did not get an "undefined error" msg instead. This should work tho...

```
a = 0

while(a < 10):
  print(a)
  a +=1
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to achieve this is by installing the [Coderunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension.  It will automatically show your print statements in your VS Code terminal.